# Proving this recurrence

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, recurrence-relations, problem-solving

Prove that the function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ that satisfies the relation
$$f(n + 1) = nf(n) + (n − 1)f(n − 1) +\dots + f(1) + 1,$$
with $f(0) = 1$, it satisfies the relation $f(n + 1) = (n + 1)f(n)$`

In addition, conclude what the function $f$ is.

Can anyone help me solve this recurrence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that by the given relation, replacing $n+1$ with $n$ , we have
$$f(n) = (n-1)f(n-1) + (n − 2)f(n − 2) +\dots + f(1) + 1,$$
Hence
$$f(n + 1) = nf(n) + [(n − 1)f(n − 1) +\dots + f(1) + 1]=nf(n) +f(n)=(n+1)f(n).$$
Therefore (for $n\geq 4$),
$$f(n)=nf(n-1)=n(n-1)f(n-2)=n(n-1)(n-2)f(n-3).$$
Now are you able to find $f$ such that $f(0)=1$?

Comment: Is f some sort of well known function? Since the question asks what f is?

Comment: @Wizard Yes, it is a known function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial